# Use Windows API from C# to set primary monitor

Tags: c#, windows, sdk

I'm trying to use the Windows API to set the primary monitor. It doesn't seem to work - my screen just flicks and nothing happens.

```
    public const int DM_ORIENTATION = 0x00000001;
public const int DM_PAPERSIZE = 0x00000002;
public const int DM_PAPERLENGTH = 0x00000004;
public const int DM_PAPERWIDTH = 0x00000008;
public const int DM_SCALE = 0x00000010;
public const int DM_POSITION = 0x00000020;
public const int DM_NUP = 0x00000040;
public const int DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION = 0x00000080;
public const int DM_COPIES = 0x00000100;
public const int DM_DEFAULTSOURCE = 0x00000200;
public const int DM_PRINTQUALITY = 0x00000400;
public const int DM_COLOR = 0x00000800;
public const int DM_DUPLEX = 0x00001000;
public const int DM_YRESOLUTION = 0x00002000;
public const int DM_TTOPTION = 0x00004000;
public const int DM_COLLATE = 0x00008000;
public const int DM_FORMNAME = 0x00010000;
public const int DM_LOGPIXELS = 0x00020000;
public const int DM_BITSPERPEL = 0x00040000;
public const int DM_PELSWIDTH = 0x00080000;
public const int DM_PELSHEIGHT = 0x00100000;
public const int DM_DISPLAYFLAGS = 0x00200000;
public const int DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY = 0x00400000;
public const int DM_ICMMETHOD = 0x00800000;
public const int DM_ICMINTENT = 0x01000000;
public const int DM_MEDIATYPE = 0x02000000;
public const int DM_DITHERTYPE = 0x04000000;
public const int DM_PANNINGWIDTH = 0x08000000;
public const int DM_PANNINGHEIGHT = 0x10000000;
public const int DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT = 0x20000000;

public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01;
public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02;
public const int CDS_SET_PRIMARY = 0x00000010;

public const long DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE = -2;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED = -3;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS = -4;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM = -5;
public const long DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW = -6;

    public static void SetPrimary(Screen screen)
{
  DISPLAY_DEVICE d = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
  DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
  d.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(d);
  uint deviceID = 1;
  User_32.EnumDisplayDevices(null, deviceID, ref  d, 0); // 
  User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(d.DeviceName, 0, ref dm);
  dm.dmPelsWidth = 2560;
  dm.dmPelsHeight = 1600;
  dm.dmPositionX = screen.Bounds.Right;
  dm.dmFields = DM_POSITION | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
  User_32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(d.DeviceName, ref dm, IntPtr.Zero, CDS_SET_PRIMARY, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
SetPrimary(Screen.AllScreens[1])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Here is the full code based on ADBailey's solution:

```
public class MonitorChanger
{
    public static void SetAsPrimaryMonitor(uint id)
    {
        var device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        var deviceMode = new DEVMODE();
        device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

        NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, id, ref device, 0);
        NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, -1, ref deviceMode);
        var offsetx = deviceMode.dmPosition.x;
        var offsety = deviceMode.dmPosition.y;
        deviceMode.dmPosition.x = 0;
        deviceMode.dmPosition.y = 0;

        NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
            device.DeviceName,
            ref deviceMode,
            (IntPtr)null,
            (ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_SET_PRIMARY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NORESET),
            IntPtr.Zero);

        device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

        // Update remaining devices
        for (uint otherid = 0; NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, otherid, ref device, 0); otherid++)
        {
            if (device.StateFlags.HasFlag(DisplayDeviceStateFlags.AttachedToDesktop) && otherid != id)
            {
                device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
                var otherDeviceMode = new DEVMODE();

                NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, -1, ref otherDeviceMode);

                otherDeviceMode.dmPosition.x -= offsetx;
                otherDeviceMode.dmPosition.y -= offsety;

                NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                    device.DeviceName,
                    ref otherDeviceMode,
                    (IntPtr)null,
                    (ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NORESET),
                    IntPtr.Zero);

            }

            device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
        }

        // Apply settings
        NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(null, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)null, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NONE, (IntPtr)null);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DEVMODE
{
    public const int CCHDEVICENAME = 32;
    public const int CCHFORMNAME = 32;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME)]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)]
    public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(34)]
    public Int16 dmDriverVersion;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(36)]
    public Int16 dmSize;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(38)]
    public Int16 dmDriverExtra;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(40)]
    public UInt32 dmFields;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
    Int16 dmOrientation;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(46)]
    Int16 dmPaperSize;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(48)]
    Int16 dmPaperLength;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(50)]
    Int16 dmPaperWidth;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
    Int16 dmScale;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(54)]
    Int16 dmCopies;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
    Int16 dmDefaultSource;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(58)]
    Int16 dmPrintQuality;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
    public POINTL dmPosition;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
    public Int32 dmDisplayOrientation;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
    public Int32 dmDisplayFixedOutput;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(60)]
    public short dmColor; // See note below!
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(62)]
    public short dmDuplex; // See note below!
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(64)]
    public short dmYResolution;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(66)]
    public short dmTTOption;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(68)]
    public short dmCollate; // See note below!
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(72)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHFORMNAME)]
    public string dmFormName;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(102)]
    public Int16 dmLogPixels;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(104)]
    public Int32 dmBitsPerPel;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(108)]
    public Int32 dmPelsWidth;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(112)]
    public Int32 dmPelsHeight;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
    public Int32 dmDisplayFlags;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
    public Int32 dmNup;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(120)]
    public Int32 dmDisplayFrequency;
}

public enum DISP_CHANGE : int
{
    Successful = 0,
    Restart = 1,
    Failed = -1,
    BadMode = -2,
    NotUpdated = -3,
    BadFlags = -4,
    BadParam = -5,
    BadDualView = -6
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int cb;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string DeviceName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceString;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceKey;
}

[Flags()]
public enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int
{
    /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
    AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
    MultiDriver = 0x2,
    /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
    PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
    /// <summary>Represents a pseudo device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.</summary>
    MirroringDriver = 0x8,
    /// <summary>The device is VGA compatible.</summary>
    VGACompatible = 0x10,
    /// <summary>The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display.</summary>
    Removable = 0x20,
    /// <summary>The device has more display modes than its output devices support.</summary>
    ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
    Remote = 0x4000000,
    Disconnect = 0x2000000,
}

[Flags()]
public enum ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags : uint
{
    CDS_NONE = 0,
    CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x00000001,
    CDS_TEST = 0x00000002,
    CDS_FULLSCREEN = 0x00000004,
    CDS_GLOBAL = 0x00000008,
    CDS_SET_PRIMARY = 0x00000010,
    CDS_VIDEOPARAMETERS = 0x00000020,
    CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000100,
    CDS_DISABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000200,
    CDS_RESET = 0x40000000,
    CDS_RESET_EX = 0x20000000,
    CDS_NORESET = 0x10000000
}

public class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(string lpszDeviceName, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    // A signature for ChangeDisplaySettingsEx with a DEVMODE struct as the second parameter won't allow you to pass in IntPtr.Zero, so create an overload
    public static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(string lpszDeviceName, IntPtr lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(string lpDevice, uint iDevNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINTL
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ADBaley and Vladimir. I could use this for our school installations (Teacher PC+Scaler->Beamer) here is the code for everybody:
https://github.com/Grunge/setDisplayRes
Greetings and Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I ran into exactly the same problem, both from C# and after following the advice here to try it in C++.  I eventually discovered that the thing the Microsoft documentation doesn't make clear is that the request to set the primary monitor will be ignored (but with the operation reported as successful!) unless you also set the position of the monitor to (0, 0) on the DEVMODE struct.  Of course, this means that you also need to shift the positions of your other monitors so that they stay in the same place relative to the new primary monitor.  Per the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), call ChangeDisplaySettingsEx for each monitor with the CDS_NORESET flag and then make a final call with everything null.

The following code worked for me:

```
    public static void SetAsPrimaryMonitor(uint id)
    {
        var device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        var deviceMode = new DEVMODE();
        device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

        NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, id, ref device, 0);
        NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, -1, ref deviceMode);
        var offsetx = deviceMode.dmPosition.x;
        var offsety = deviceMode.dmPosition.y;
        deviceMode.dmPosition.x = 0;
        deviceMode.dmPosition.y = 0;

        NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
            device.DeviceName, 
            ref deviceMode, 
            (IntPtr)null, 
            (ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_SET_PRIMARY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NORESET), 
            IntPtr.Zero);

        device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

        // Update remaining devices
        for (uint otherid = 0; NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, otherid, ref device, 0); otherid++)
        {
            if (device.StateFlags.HasFlag(DisplayDeviceStateFlags.AttachedToDesktop) && otherid != id)
            {
                device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
                var otherDeviceMode = new DEVMODE();

                NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, -1, ref otherDeviceMode);

                otherDeviceMode.dmPosition.x -= offsetx;
                otherDeviceMode.dmPosition.y -= offsety;

                NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                    device.DeviceName,
                    ref otherDeviceMode,
                    (IntPtr)null,
                    (ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NORESET),
                    IntPtr.Zero);

            }

            device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
        }

        // Apply settings
        NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(null, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)null, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NONE, (IntPtr)null);
    }
```

Note that a signature for ChangeDisplaySettingsEx with a DEVMODE struct as the second parameter obviously won't allow you to pass in IntPtr.Zero.  Create yourself two different signatures for the same extern call, i.e.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(string lpszDeviceName, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(string lpszDeviceName, IntPtr lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: I'm about to try this code out and experiment, but can you comment a bit about what the strategy for shifting the positions of the other monitors should be? I haven't found much documentation on MSDN about what the positions mean and how they need to relate to each other, whether they should be negative or positive, etc. Your example moves all the other monitors leftward and upward by the previous position of the new primary monitor -- what's the rationale for doing this? Not quite seeing it.

Comment: I guess to make a conjecture -- I'm assuming the whole 2D plane is fair game, positive or negative, and the relative positioning just matters for mouse wraparound?

Comment: I don't have a chance to try it at the moment @user1454265 (so hopefully you'll verify what I'm saying when you do), but my recollection is that the top left corner of the primary monitor is always (0,0), so I wrote the above in such a way that the monitors retain their relative positioning when you change the primary one (crucial for me particularly as I have three monitors of different sizes in odd places).

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really help you with the winapi-stuff but if you are using a Nvidia card you may have a look at the [NVcontrolPanel Api Documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf)
Then you could make the secondary output your primary using `rundll32.exe NvCpl.dll,dtcfg primary 2`
Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation for ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533235(VS.85).aspx), "the dmSize member must be initialized to the size, in bytes, of the DEVMODE structure."  Furthermore, [the EnumDisplaySettings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533265(VS.85).aspx) states, "Before calling EnumDisplaySettings, set the dmSize member to sizeof(DEVMODE), and set the dmDriverExtra member to indicate the size, in bytes, of the additional space available to receive private driver data". I don't see this happening in the code sample given in the question; that's one reason why it may be failing.

Additionally, you might have errors in the definitions of the DEVMODE and DISPLAY_DEVICE structs, which were not included in the question. [Roger Lipscombe's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195267/use-windows-api-from-c-to-set-primary-monitor#195272) to get it working from C/C++ first is an excellent way to rule out this type of problem.

Finally, check the return value from ChangeDisplaySettingsEx and see if that gives a clue as to why it might be failing.