# Programming Monitor positioning

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, monitor

When I plug my laptop into my docking station, I want my external monitor to be the attached, and the primary monitor, positioned on the left hand side.

To do this, I have to go into control panel, open display properties, position the monitors, attach, set to primary, then hit ok.

Is there a way to do this in code???

I'd prefer C# .net 3.5 but I'd settle for anything!

This question got closed, so I've reasked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837613/setting-my-display-resolution)

Comment: Just because you write "Is there a way to do this in code???" doesn't make this a programming question.

Comment: Still, this has annoyed me for years! Vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this before, but see here:

[Linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195267/use-windows-api-from-c-to-set-primary-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Set as primary/default' on your external monitor in display settings.  Also use extend my display.  I have the same setup at home with my Gateway Vista laptop.

Comment: Are you guessing or have you tried this???

When I unplug laptop, the laptop display becomes the "primary/default".  Whe I plug the laptop back in, the laptop is still the "primary/default"