# C# modify monitor position

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've searched for an answer for this and all I have read were only Window positions for multiple monitors.

I have a program that, at a push of a `NotifyIcon`, will enable/disable my third monitor, which works fine.  But every time it enables it, the position of the third monitor will go back to the default.  Every time, I have to go into settings and change the monitor position.  I want my program to do that automatically.

The first picture shows what the default is and the second picture is what I want.

[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Monitor position is stored in the registry, so if nothing, else you can override it every time you enable it: https://superuser.com/questions/106749/what-registry-key-or-windows-file-determines-where-monitors-are-placed-in-a-mult

Comment: Oh.  Let me try that.

Comment: Ok.  Then after changing the reg values, how do I update/reset the settings so it takes place?

Comment: You have to pinvoke ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(), specifying a different DEVMODE.dmPosition.  Google away, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23044185/17034) is one hit.